# Getting "SQL command not properly ended" error

Tags: java, oracle, sqlexception

Why i am getting below error while running this query in eclipse?

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Code:

```
String policy = "select p.policy_id,i.insurance_type,c.reason,i.insured_amount,i.max_claim_amount,c.claim_status from claim as c join policy as p on c.policy_id=p.policy_id join insurance as i on p.insurance_id=i.insurance_id where c.user_id=?";
PreparedStatement policyst = con.prepareStatement(policy);
policyst.setString(1, userId);
ResultSet policyrs = policyst.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle does not support `as` for table aliasing; you should remove them:

```
SELECT p.policy_id,
       i.insurance_type,
       c.reason,
       i.insured_amount,
       i.max_claim_amount,
       c.claim_status
  FROM claim c
       JOIN policy p ON c.policy_id = p.policy_id
       JOIN insurance i ON p.insurance_id = i.insurance_id
 WHERE c.user_id = ?
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove word "AS" from your statement